# SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE : Not able to read environment properties from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to read environment variables from my application.properties
`domains.integrationService=${INTEGRATION_SERVICE_DOMAIN:http://localhost:1337}`.

The env property is set inside my docker container (checked it), but somehow spring is unable to read it from `.properties`. Thus, it ends up setting `http://localhost:1337`.

This worked fine in other projects using 2.0.0 version of SpringBoot.

I think they discarded this feature. I don't want to hardcode these values in my `.properties` in the project.

My `.env` in docker.

```
INTEGRATION_SERVICE_DOMAIN=https://dummy.com
```

My Docker run command

`docker run  -d  -p 1100:1100 --restart unless-stopped --env-file ~/.env --network=\"host\" -v /var/log/dummy-project:/usr/src/app/logs -v /tmp:/usr/src/app/tmp --name dummy-project`

Let me know if there are any solutions.

Comment: I doubt Spring has broken backward compatibility in such fundamental area like property management. Please provide more details how you're setting the props in docker, how you're accessing them in the application and in general what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Added description. This isn't dockerization issue. properties don't read env variables when I run the app from local without docker.

Answer (score 0):

Just trust Spring Boot to do the job properly out-of-the-box.

As explained [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), the PropertySource will first read the properties file, then override the loaded values with the ones from the environment variables (and other locations, see the doc for all possibilities and precedence order).

So if your application.properties contains :

```
domains.integrationService=http://localhost:1337
```

you may override this "default" value by setting a similarily-named environment variable. In this example, at least `domains.integrationService` and `DOMAINS_INTEGRATION_SERVICE` environment variables would be picked up automatically to override the value from your `application.properties`. It will not reverse words by itself though, so `INTEGRATION_SERVICE_DOMAIN` won't work.

Try it (outside of docker) with :

```
export DOMAINS_INTEGRATION_SERVICE=https://dummy.com
```